# Performance of "x IN (a,b)" vs. "x = a OR x = b"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there likely to be any difference in performance on SQL Server between:

```
where (anothercolumn=17) OR (anothercolumn=23) OR (anothercolumn=33)
```

and

```
where anothercolumn IN (17,23,33)
```

Comment: They should be identical. Look at the query plan in SSMS to verify for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they optimize exactly the same way, and you should never see any performance difference whatsoever. The only exception would be if you have a very large amount of columns and the actual network performance of transferring the query text itself introduces some latency (or exceeds the transfer size). If that happens you should hire new network people.

Comment: LOL, hope you aren't serious :D